# Text input is saved when clicking on the field not button below?

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore

I have some code that saves some text to Firestore and works but it only works when you click the text field after typing.

This saves to Firestore. I have changed the text between ("...") after getElementById to the id of the button but that does not save anything. But if I have it as the id of the text field the text is saved when clicking on the text field after typing.

```
document.getElementById("hrtitle").addEventListener("click", function saveHeroTitle() {
        
        const title = document.getElementById('hrtitle').value;
        console.log(title);

        const heroTitleRef = doc(db, "pages", "homePage");

        // something around line 42 vv
        setDoc(heroTitleRef, {
            heroText: title,
        }, {merge: true}).then(function() {
            console.log("Hero Title Saved");
        }).catch(function(error){
        console.log("Error: ", error);
    });
});
```

Code for the text Field and Button.

```
<label for="uetitle">Update Hero Title</label>
<input type="text" id="hrtitle" name="hrtitle">
                      
                      <button class="save-button" id="hrtitleSave" type="submit">Save</button>
```

How do I get the text to save on the button click instead?

Comment: Can you change ID of input field to something else? ID of the button seems to be same. Also it should be `document.getElementById("hrtitleSave")`

Comment: yes the text field id was a mistake while coping to here, I never had 'Save' with it in my original code. When I do add the Save like you suggested above, nothing gets saved?

Comment: Try changing button type to `"button"`, perhaps the default action is being executed? Is the page refreshing when you click button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are using the wrong id for getting your button. This code should be working:

```
document.getElementById("hrtitleSave").addEventListener("click", function saveHeroTitle() {
    
    const title = document.getElementById('hrtitle').value;
    console.log(title);

    const heroTitleRef = doc(db, "pages", "homePage");

    // something around line 42 vv
    setDoc(heroTitleRef, {
        heroText: title,
    }, {merge: true}).then(function() {
        console.log("Hero Title Saved");
    }).catch(function(error){
    console.log("Error: ", error);
    });
});
```

__

```
<label for="uetitle">Update Hero Title</label>
<input type="text" id="hrtitle" name="hrtitle">            
<button class="save-button" id="hrtitleSave" type="submit">Save</button>
```

Comment: Hi I had changed that around before that still didn't work. @Dharmaraj answer of changing type of the button to button did work (the id was also set to the same one of the button id)

Comment: Strange! I have personally tested the above and it worked for me... Make sure your changes are being applied and clear your browser cache